# inbuilt std::__gcd() function for c++ is not working on Mac OS Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, macos-catalina

Inbuilt __gcd() function is not working on Xcode macOS.
I have run the following code on Xcode (macOS Catalina) it shows an error
"Use of undeclared identifier '__gcd' ".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "gcd(6, 20) = " << __gcd(6, 20) << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

please help me out

Comment: The double leading underscore in `__gcd` means that it's an implementation-defined symbol, and possibly private.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the one from [`<numeric>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd) if you compile with `-std=c++17`

```
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "gcd(6, 20) = " << std::gcd(6, 20) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `__gcd` is an internal implementation detail hence the `__` prefix, you should not be depending on that in your code.

Comment: @Adarshyadav it was available in <numeric> since c++17

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking,
Use the following function below header files, as gcd is not working in mac m1:

```cpp
int __gcd(int a, int b) { 
    if (b == 0) { 
        return a; 
    } 
    return gcd(b, a % b); 
}
```

Then you can use `__gcd(a, b)` function easily and efficiently.

Comment: Please don't post repetitive answer. Same answer is already posted by other people.

Answer (score 0):

std::gcd() is available in c++17

otherwise,

The GCD for two non negative integers is easily calculated:

`int gcd(int a, int b){  int c = a % b;  while(c != 0)  {    a = b;    b = c;    c = a % b;  }  return b;}`

cf. https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/358629-built-in-c-command-for-gcd/3354131/

Answer (score 0):

Some answers, here, contain Euclidean based code for calculating gcd. For example :

```
int gcd(int a, int b) { if(b == 0){return a;} return gcd(b, a % b); }
```

You will have to take care about the order of actual arguments you pass to this function. Code is based on assumtion that `a>0`, `b>0` and `a>=b`.

Code can be modified to remove these assumptions.

```
int gcd(int a,int b)
{
    if(a<0 or b<0)
        return -1;
    
    if(a>b)
        return gcd(b,a);
    
    if(a==0)
        return b;
    
    //Due to Euclidean algorithm
    return gcd(a,b%a); 
}
```

If you stick to first version, you will have to take care about sending arguments according to the above assumptions.